# How can I have extra space for x axis in this line plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, line, axis

I am trying to construct a line plot as follows. I need extra space for the symbolic x axis so that I can add notation $\tau=\bar{Y}*{1,1}-\bar{Y}*{1,0}$ next to the brace. is there anyway to do this? thanks,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,  ylabel={$BMI$}, ymax=90,ymin=30, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, 
    legend style={at={(0.5,0.2),anchor=north}
        },
    symbolic x coords={Baseline(T0), PostRandomization(T1)}, xtick=data]
    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
        (Baseline(T0),80) (PostRandomization(T1),70)};
    \addlegendentry{Control}
    \addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},blue,thick,dashed] coordinates {
        (Baseline(T0),79.5) (PostRandomization(T1),50) };
    \addlegendentry{Treatment}
    \draw [thick,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate] 
      (axis cs:{PostRandomization(T1)},70) --
        node[below=5pt]{$\tau=\bar{Y}_{1,1}-\bar{Y}_{1,0}$} 
      (axis cs:{PostRandomization(T1)},50);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just put the brace outside of the axis and at the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,  ylabel={$BMI$}, ymax=90,ymin=30, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, 
    legend style={at={(0.5,0.2),anchor=north}
        },
    symbolic x coords={Baseline(T0), PostRandomization(T1)}, xtick=data]
    \addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
        (Baseline(T0),80) (PostRandomization(T1),70)};
    \addlegendentry{Control}
    \addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},blue,thick,dashed] coordinates {
        (Baseline(T0),79.5) (PostRandomization(T1),50) };
    \addlegendentry{Treatment}
    \path (axis cs:{PostRandomization(T1)},70) coordinate(p1)
        (axis cs:{PostRandomization(T1)},50)  coordinate(p2);
\end{axis}
\draw [thick,decoration={brace,raise=2pt},decorate] 
  (p1) --
    node[right=3pt]{$\tau=\bar{Y}_{1,1}-\bar{Y}_{1,0}$} 
  (p2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]